# Fill and paint each gridview cell individually?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I have sql table dbo.Clicks that looks like this:

```
ColNum        Color        RowNum        Message
1             Gold         1             Text1
1             Black        2             Text2
2             Red          2             MoreText
2             Blue         3             TextX
```

My stored procedure returns this same data like this. This is underlying `datatable`:

```
Col1          Col2
-----------------------
Gold          (null)
Black         Red
(null)        Blue
```

I fill each cell in `RowDataBound`:

```
protected void GridViewClicks_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            cell.BackColor = ConvertFromHexToColor(cell.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works because it fills the cells with its corresponding backcolor.

The issue now is that I also need to display the contents of my sql table [dbo.Clicks] in each cell. And that's where I'm stuck.

An alternative is that each datatable cell includes the color and the text, something like this, if I use the sample data. Then I parse it:

```
Col1          Col2
Gold/Text1    (null)
Black/Text2   Red/MoreText
(null)        Blue/TextX
```

But I'm thinking there has to be a more elegant way of doing this. For me, this solution's pretty ugly.

My gridview looks like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewClicks" runat="server" ShowHeader="False" onrowdatabound="GridViewClicks_RowDataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DataRowView` in the `OnRowDataBound` event and get the individual values from a row and apply them to specific cells.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    //cast the dataitem back to a datarowview
    DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

    //use the data from the datarowview to specify color and contents for specific cells
    e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = Color.FromName(row["Color"].ToString());
    e.Row.Cells[0].Text = row["RowNum"].ToString();
    e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = Color.FromName(row["Color"].ToString());
    e.Row.Cells[1].Text = row["Message"].ToString();
}
```

UPDATE

If the GridView has 3 columns, and the DataSource 6, with alternating text/color values you can create a loop

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    //cast the dataitem back to a datarowview
    DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

    //loop all the items in the datarowview (not equal to columns in grid)
    for (int i = 0; i < drv.Row.ItemArray.Length; i++)
    {
        //check if it is an uneven column
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i / 2].Text = drv[i].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i / 2].BackColor = Color.FromName(drv[i].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I noticed you are setting a fixed value for the `Cells`. I don't know how many columns the datatable will have. Would your answer still work?

Comment: That rather depends on how the column and their colors are received from the datasource. If it is `text,color,text,color` etc you can make a loop in the rowdatabound event that colors each `cell -1`

Comment: Thanks very much for the update. With  your update I was able to change the `for` loop for my case. And it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template fields with labels and assign style attribute with Eval.

```
public class SomeData
    {
        public  string Data1 { get; set; }
        public string Data2 { get; set; }

        public string Color1 { get; set; }

        public string Color2 { get; set; }

    }

 List<SomeData> lstData = new List<SomeData>()
            {

                new SomeData() {Data1 = "AAA", Color1 = "Red", Data2 = "ZZZ", Color2 = "Green"},
                new SomeData() {Data1 = "BBB", Color1 = "Blue", Data2 = "PPP", Color2 = "Gold"},
                new SomeData() {Data1 = "CCC", Color1 = "Red", Data2 = "ZZZ", Color2 = "Yellow"},

            };

            grdView.DataSource = lstData;
            grdView.DataBind();
```

Create Gridview with template field like below

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdView" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
       <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblColor1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Data1") %>' style= <%# String.Concat("background-color:",Eval("Color1")) %> ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblColor2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Data2") %>' style= <%# String.Concat("background-color:",Eval("Color2")) %>></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

This bit will do the trick for you

```
style= <%# String.Concat("background-color:",Eval("Color2")) %>
```

[image: This is how your gridview will look like]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would this work with the sql server table or the datatable? Also, does this take into account that I don't know how many columns there will be?

Comment: It will work with data from any data source. You will need to know number of columns as gridview  has template fields you need to specify for each column in your database table. .