# Change gridview row text color based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, gridview

I am populating gridview dynamically and I need to set forecolor to red if values are `<=0`. I can probably use the below code if my grid is static and since my grid is dynamic how can I check for numbers in cell values to change forecolor.

I need to check each cell value whether it is `<=0` then set forecolor to red.

**Code:**

For static grid

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    e.Row.Cells[3].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

I also tried the below code and it didn't work.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[i];
        int quantity = int.Parse(cell.Text);
        if (quantity == 0)
        {
            cell.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Please provide suggestions or inputs on how this can be achieved.

**Update 1:**

I have updated my code as below and still not able to get the desired color.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    TableCell cell = row.Cells[i];
                    int quantity = int.Parse(cell.Text);
                    if (quantity <= 0)
                    {
                        cell.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                }
            }

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {

            }

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {                    

            }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill and paint each gridview cell individually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290650/fill-and-paint-each-gridview-cell-individually)

Answer (score 1):

I think this one would be the best way

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in YourGridViewID.Rows)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < YourGridViewID.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
               TableCell cell = row.Cells[i];
                int quantity = int.Parse(cell.Text);
                if (quantity <= 0)
                {
                    cell.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                } 
    }
}
```

Comment: My columns are dynamic and the above one is application only for static grid.

Comment: Edited My Answer Sorry for the last one i did not read your question's last line properly :p

Comment: Updated my post with the try and unable to change color. Please correct me if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: i think your code is perfect but as you say you are still not able to change the color  so there must be any exception. try to debug this foreach loop and see is it doing it work perfectly or throwing any exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162910/discussion-between-syed-munis-ali-and-vicky).

Comment: I came to chat.